# Changing color in HTML table based on passed variable

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am trying to create a table in python Flask, however I have a bit problem with changing color of each line of table. This is my HTML file content:

```
<tr class=fail>
    <td class="title">Status</td>
    <td>{{ query.get("status") }}</td>
</tr>
```

where query is a python dictionary which holds two states for status:

`query = {"status":"Success"}` or `query = {"status":"Fail"}`

and this is my css file part:

```
tr.success {
    background-color: #21eaab !important;
}

tr.fail {
    background-color: #f56279 !important;
}
```

**Problem:**

all problem happens when I change HTML class from class=fail or class=success to `class={{ query.get('status') }}` as I wish to don't do it by hand and just pass the value of dictionary to it.

**Attempts:**

I also tried to change .css content a bit as:

```
tr.Success {
    background-color: #21eaab !important;
}

tr.Fail {
    background-color: #f56279 !important;
}
```

even `<tr class={{ query.status }}>` or `<tr class={{ query.get("status") }}>` which non of these solutions were not applicable. The problem should be a tiny problem which I can't find.

Comment: When you did `<td>{{ query.get("status") }}</td>` what value appeared inside of the table cell when you rendered the page?

Comment: it prints Success or Fail in the table

Comment: Sometimes, row styling is overridden by cell styling. Try using `tr.Success td { ... }` and `tr.Fail td { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `{{ query.get("status") }}` prints "Success" or "Fail" exactly as stated, then this should work:

```
<tr class={{ query.get("status").lower() }}>
    <td class="title">Status</td>
    <td>{{ query.get("status") }}</td>
</tr>

tr.success {
    background-color: #21eaab !important;
}

tr.fail {
    background-color: #f56279 !important;
}
```

Keep in mind that `!important` will only help if you have CSS conflicts within that same scope of specificity. So it's quite possible that your code was working to begin with, but you have a more specific style selector that is overriding your intended result.

For instance you might need to do something like this:

```
tr.success td {
    background-color: #21eaab !important;
}

tr.fail td {
    background-color: #f56279 !important;
}
```

But this may result in a thin white line between the cells doing it this way. It will help you better troubleshoot if you are having a specificity scoping conflict, though.

Comment: I tried this solution however, there is an error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'toLowerCase'

Comment: I also checked {{ query.get("status") }}.toLowerCase() which in this case, it does not raise any error but colors again not getting changed

Comment: Sorry I was using React syntax instead of jinja. lower() should work for your case, however if the result still doesn't reflect your styles, then you must have a CSS conflict which we can't know without seeing the rest of your styles. I have edited my answer for jinja using lower()